# Proof of correctness of Putzers algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, summation, exponentiation

I have a question regarding the proof (seen below) of Putzers algorithm for matrix exponentiation. It's written by our danish lecturer at the university, so I translated the important parts into somewhat readable english.

What I don't understand is the line:

$$\sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (\lambda_{k+1} r_{k+1}(t) + r_r(t))P_k - A \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} r_{k+1}(t)P_k = \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (-r_{k+1}(t)(A - \lambda_{k+1}I)P_k + r_k(t)P_k)$$

Can anyone tell me how to go from the left hand side to the right hand side?

Definition:
Let $A \in Mat_{n, n}(\mathbb{C})$. Let $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ (counting algebraic multiplicity). Let $P_0 = I$ and for $k = 1, \dotsc, n$, $P_k = \Pi^{k}_{j = 1}(A - \lambda_j I)$. Define
\begin{equation*}
Q(t) = \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} r_{k+1}(t)P_k
\end{equation*}
where $r_1(t) = e^{\lambda_1 t}$ og for $k = k, \dotsc, n$
\begin{equation}
r_k(t) = e^{\lambda_k t} \int^{t}_{0} e^{-\lambda_k s} r_{k-1}(s) \, d s
\end{equation}
It is now true that $Q(0) = I$ and $Q'(t) = A Q(t)$

Proof:
We observe that $r_1(0) = 1$ and $r_k(0) = 0$ for $k = 2, \dotsc, n$, so $Q(0) = P_0 = I$.

For $k > 1$ we now have that
\begin{align*}
r'_k(t) &= \lambda_k e^{\lambda_k t} \int^{t}_{0} e^{-\lambda_k s} r_{k-1}(s) \, ds +
   e^{\lambda_k t} e^{-\lambda_k t} r_{k-1}(t)\\
  &= \lambda_k r_k(t) + r_{k-1}(t)
\end{align*}
Defining $r_0(t) = 0$ we also see that this is true for $k = 1$.

We now have
\begin{equation*}
Q'(t) = \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0}r'_{k+1}(t) P_k = \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (\lambda_k r_k(t) + r_{k-1}(t))P_k
\end{equation*}
And therefore
\begin{align*}
Q'(t) - A Q(t) &= \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (\lambda_{k+1} r_{k+1}(t) + r_r(t))P_k - A \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} r_{k+1}(t)P_k\\
    &= \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (-r_{k+1}(t)(A - \lambda_{k+1}I)P_k + r_k(t)P_k)\\
    &= \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0} (-r_{k+1}(t)P_{k+1} + r_k(t)P_k)\\
    &= -r_n(t)P_n\\
    &= 0
\end{align*}
Since $(-1)^n P_n = p_A(A) = 0$ from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything into one sum, rearrange the summands (we omit $\sum$s and $P_k$s below):

$$ (\color{Blue}{\lambda_{k+1}} \color{Teal}{r_{k+1}} + \color{Purple}{r_k}) - \color{Blue}{A}\color{Teal}{r_{k+1}} = -\color{Teal}{r_{k+1}}\color{Blue}{(A-\lambda_{k+1}I)} + \color{Purple}{r_k}.$$